# put values of a list into a object

Tags: java, list

I have an object `Person` with the following fields:
`firstName`, `secondName`, `age`, `nationallity`, `address`, `phoneNr`.

And the list: `['John', 'Smith', '35', 'american', 'San Francisco', '+0324 235 327']`.

I would like to put the values of the list into the object `Person`, without using the classic method of setting each value.

I want to avoid this:

```
person.setFirstName(list.get(0));
person.setSecondName(list.get(1));
person.setAge(list.get(2));
person.setNationallity(list.get(3));
person.setAddress(list.get(4));
person.setPhoneNumber(list.get(5));
```

My object has more fields than the ones I've put here as example (about 15), and I want to avoid writting a lot of code.

So my question is there a more elegant way of dumping all the values from the list into the object? I was thinking that in `Java 8` maybe is there something but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: write a setter that will accept list, create person object and return it.

Comment: any particular reason why you are not using a Map in the first place?

Comment: You should create a method that accept a list. You can do also do it with a for loop and forcibly set values using reflection ( `Person.class.getFields()` ) but that is extremely unsafe and an awful practice.

Comment: Java class members do not have a order like List. What you are asking is unnatural in Java and is not good class design. You bend Java for your convenience.

Comment: Perhaps the best question is: Why do you have that list in the first place? Sounds like your problem is there. Can't you get to data in a Person directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dump all values from the list into object, but you can add a new contructor in your Person Class, with a list as parameter like this :

```
public Person(List<String> list) {
    this.firstName(list.get(0));
    this.secondName(list.get(1));
    this.age(list.get(2));
    this.nationallity(list.get(3));
    this.address(list.get(4));
    this.phoneNumber(list.get(5)); 
}
```

and the call will be like :

```
Person person = new Person(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is good, there is one trick that can make it easier to work with though. This is especially relevant if there are a large number of entries such as the 15 mentioned in the question:

```
public Person(List<String> list) {
    int index = 0;
    this.firstName(index++);
    this.secondName(index++);
    this.age(index++);
    this.nationallity(index++);
    this.address(index++);
    this.phoneNumber(index++); 
}
```

Now you can add things to the list in any position or change the order or otherwise adjust it and don't have to manually update all the indexes. It also removes the risk of human error in accidentally getting an index wrong - although you do still need to get all the fields in the right order.